# jQuery: Select elements and iterate over them until certain element appears

Tags: jquery, dom

I have an HTML like this:

```
<h2>H2 A</h2>
<h3>H3 A</h3>
<h3>H3 B</h3>
<h2>H2 B</h2>
<h3>H3 C</h3>
<h3>H3 D</h3>
```

I'm trying to iterate over (for example:) a set of H2s: find all H3 **UNDER** the H2; then go to next H2 and do the same. But I want to do that (probably) recursively and **for all the headings generally (i.e. H+level and H+level+1; h3 and h4, h4 and h5, so on)**. But up to now I've had no success.

My code is the following, I thought using nextUntil would make the job, but it makes the *each* iterate over all the elements:

```
function renderHeadingStructure(level, parent)
{
    $('h'+level)/*.nextUntil('h'+level).*/each(function(i,el){  
        // Copy item name to parent in list - now it is missing creating of an UL :- /
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
        parent.appendChild(li);

        // Here would be handy something like:
        // -> If crossed over H+level-1 (while going trough H+level)
        // -> then create an ul, recurse and then break

        if(level<6)
          renderHeadingStructure(level+1,li);  
    });
}
```

Resulting structure should be like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>H2 A</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>H3 A</a></li>
      <li><a>H3 B</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>H2 B</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>H3 C</a></li>
      <li><a>H3 D</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Result with code above is: the first H2 and all four H3s, then the second H2 and all four H3s again - all in equal li.

Can somebody please give me an advice or help solve the problem?
Thank you kindly

Comment: This would make a great interview question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did *exactly* this just a few weeks back. Recursively and with nextUntil(). The plug-in is used to generate a document outline based on the hX:s in "article" and append a list to "body" like this:

$('article').generateDocumentOutline('body');

Code here: http://code.google.com/p/sleek-php/source/browse/trunk/Sites/SleekBase/Modules/Base/JS/jQuery.generateDocumentOutline.js

Edit: it works regardless of what your highest and lowest headings are (so not limited to h2s and h3s).

Edit2: You can see it in use here: http://sleekphp.com/docs/ (the "Jump to section"-bit on the right).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. (Now I have to figure out how it works :-)

Comment: NP :) Well it starts off with the highest headings in the document (doc.find(doc.find(':header')[0].nodeName)) - assuming the highest heading comes first (which I believe it always should)). And then inside the loop it checks if the current heading has any headings that are one lower than it (var nextHeadings = heading.nextUntil('h' + currLevel, 'h' + (parseInt(currLevel, 10) + 1));) if so runs the same function on them which in turn will run them on one lower than that and then one lower than that and so on until there are no lower headings.

Comment: I'm starting from H2 (the H1 is just one and right above the list) using: `doc.find(doc.find('h2:header')[0].nodeName)`. Also the radix parameter in `parseInt(currLevel, 10)` isn't necessary, is it?

Comment: If you know you'll always be starting from h2 you can remove all of this: `doc.find('h2:header')[0].nodeName` and replace it with what it will always return (`h2`). No it isn't, but I believe it's best practice to include it :) (at least according to JSLint). Edit: But I think it would be better to not modify the plug-in but instead run it on a container that doesn't contain headings you don't want to include in the list. Like on this page: http://sleekphp.com/docs/ there's also a h1 but since I run the plug-in on `#docs` it will only generate a list based on the headings in that element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will pull all h3's after the h2. I just saw your comment, but it seems as if it might just do the job.

JMax

```
var $parent = null;
var $parentLI = null;

var $ul = $("<ul/>");

$elements = $("h2, h3");

$elements.each(function() {
   var $self = $(this);
    if ($self.get(0).tagName == "H2"){
        $parent = $self;
        $parentLI = $ul.append("<li> > " + $self.text() + "<ul></ul></li>");
    }
    else if ($self.get(0).tagName == "H3"){
        if ($parent) {
            $parentLI.find("ul").append("<li> &nbsp;&nbsp; > " + $self.text() + "</li>");
        }
    }
});

$parent.parent().append($ul);

$elements.remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This piece of code creates the following: H2 A: H3 A, H3 B, H3 C, H3 D; H2 B: H3 C, H3 D; And I have no idea how to edit it to work for purpose I need.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `h2` elements with jQuery and check if the next element is an `h3`. Make this a function and call the function within itself to keep checking for the upcoming `h3` elements.

Comment: I should have said it, but the code above is just an example. There are actually tons of elements between all the headings. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RYWwU/4/

```
var ul = "<ul></ul>";
var li = "<li></li>";
var result = $("#result");

$("h2").each(function()
{
    var heading = $(li).html("<a>" + $(this).text() + "</a>");

    var children = $(this).nextUntil("h2").filter("#container h3");

    heading.append($(ul));
    var sub = heading.find("ul");

    children.each(function()
    {
        sub.append($(li).html("<a>" + $(this).text() + "</a>"));
    });

    heading.appendTo(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It works for H2 and H3, but not for H4. I've tried to extend it - http://pastebin.com/98WikaPL But I again got into the problem I've described in my original post - it iterates over all the headings.